# ksh: to print the fourth line above the matched line and second line after the matched line

Tags: text-processing, ksh

This is the sample log file :

```
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:05:49 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables HTTP/1.1" 401 12846
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:06:51 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/rdiff/TWiki/NewUserTemplate?rev1=1.3&rev2=1.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 4523
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:10:02 -0800] "GET /mailman/listinfo/hsdivision HTTP/1.1" 200 6291
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:11:58 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/view/TWiki/WikiSyntax HTTP/1.1" 200 7352
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:20:55 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/view/Main/DCCAndPostFix HTTP/1.1" 200 5253
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:23:12 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/oops/TWiki/AppendixFileSystem?template=oopsmore¶m1=1.12¶m2=1.12 HTTP/1.1" 200 11382
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:24:16 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/view/Main/PeterThoeny HTTP/1.1" 200 4924
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:29:16 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Header_checks?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables HTTP/1.1" 401 12851
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:30:29 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/attach/Main/OfficeLocations HTTP/1.1" 401 12851
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:31:48 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/view/TWiki/WebTopicEditTemplate HTTP/1.1" 200 3732
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:32:50 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/view/Main/WebChanges HTTP/1.1" 200 40520
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:33:53 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Smtpd_etrn_restrictions?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables HTTP/1.1" 401 12851
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:35:19 -0800] "GET /mailman/listinfo/business HTTP/1.1" 200 6379
```

Need to grep the pattern "AppendixFileSystem"

```
grep -i "AppendixFileSystem*" log filename
```

Output

```
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:23:12 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/oops/TWiki/AppendixFileSystem?template=oopsmore¶m1=1.12¶m2=1.12 HTTP/1.1" 200 11382
```

I want get the 4 th line above the matched line i.e

Desired Output

```
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:06:51 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/rdiff/TWiki/NewUserTemplate?rev1=1.3&rev2=1.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 4523
```

And the 2nd after the matched line i.e

Desired Output

```
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:29:16 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Header_checks?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables HTTP/1.1" 401 12851
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
    {
        bucket[++i] = $0
    }

    /AppendixFileSystem/ {
        print bucket[i-4]
        i = 0
        found = 1
    }

    found && i == 2 {
        print bucket[i]
        found = 0
    }
' logfile.txt
```

Comment: :Can u please explain the reason behind the usage of variable `found`?

Comment: `found` is the set to true when a line matching AppendixFileSystem is encountered.  That way the script knows when it should start looking for the second line after the match.

Comment: :I am back with a query. If I want to get the sum of the values in bucket[2] (i.e `found && i == 2 { print bucket[i] found =0 }`) what should i do?